# Archetype for MyFaces-Test

Tags: unit-testing, myfaces, archetypes

I'm using mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://myfaces.apache.org
Is there a parameter for generating Unit tests for MyFaces-Test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, but it is an interesting suggestion. Please create an improvement issue on [MyFaces Test issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACESTEST). In theory, it could be good to add a goal to myfaces builder plugin that generate test classes based on the model, or in the archetype generate some default useful test cases. Personally I already have a prototype, but it is work in progress. If you want more info about it or contribute in some way (patches, comments, ...) please subscribe to [MyFaces Users and Dev mailing list](http://myfaces.apache.org/mail-lists.html) and ask questions there directly.

Comment: I saw some ideas at http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@myfaces.apache.org
They sound interesting.